# Do I need a waiver to operate a C208B with more than 9 passengers?

Tags: faa-regulations, cessna-208

Do I need a FAR Part 23 waiver for more than 9 passengers if I'm operating a [Cessna 208B Grand Caravan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_208_Caravan) under part 91?

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/why-might-a-cessna-208-need-a-far-part-23-waiver

Comment: The discussions for that suggested-as-duplicate question don't really provide an answer to this one.  It talks around the issue, but the two questions are distinct.