# Does the Cessna 208B still require a part 23 waiver to operate with 14 seats?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-certification, cessna-208

The selected answer to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/why-might-a-cessna-208-need-a-far-part-23-waiver) refers to the applicability of [part 23](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/DD3BD5D844708F3D85256687006B5C78?OpenDocument) to aircraft of nine passengers or less. Other countries certified the 208B with as many as fourteen passenger seats, using a waiver to allow the extra seats while relying on the FAA nine seat single engine certification base. The FAA normally required aircraft with ten to nineteen seats to be multi-engine.

The part 23 rewrite allows certification using [ASTM standards](https://www.astm.org/f44-general-aviation-aircraft.htm), which provides for "level 4" occupancy of up to nineteen seats, and has a propulsion matrix with space for level 4 single engine aircraft. If the 208B were certified using the ASTM standards, would it still require a waiver to operate with more than nine passengers outside the US? Would it now be legal to operate this way inside the US under part 135?

Comment: I believe this is done under a supplemental type certificate.  And im pretty certain that the 14 passenger configuration is only applicable for skydiving operations.  (Where temporary "passengers" sit along the sides, either on a bench seat or on the floor)  If you ride in a Caravan you will quickly realize that there just isn't space for 14 conventional passenger seats.  If I was more confident I would make this an answer...

Comment: @MichaelHall This is the Grand Caravan which is bigger than the 208A model, but still I agree it is tight. The Cessna website shows the layout, four rows of 2+1 behind two crew seats.

Comment: yeah, I kinda used "Caravan" in the family context, to include both models.  (Which I have flown)  I actually did not know it entailed 2+1 rows, dang that must be tight!  And that's why I commented instead of answering...  Thanks for straightening me out.